# Get Information for an Accordion Component to Match with Data Displayed on Another Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pretty new to react, and I am trying to created an accordion component in a project I'm working on. I'm trying to get the ingredients for a product saved in my database to be listed in the accordion component. The issue that I'm having is that I need it to match with the specific product shown on my product screen. I would really appreciate any help or advice on how to do this.
Thank you!

Accordion.js in my components

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import '/Accordion.css'
import { IconContext } from 'react-icons';
import { FiPlus, FiMinus } from 'react-icons/fi';


const Accordion = () => {
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);

  const toggle = index => {
    if (clicked === index) {
      //if clicked question is already active, then close it
      return setClicked(null);
    }

    setClicked(index);
  };

  return (
    <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: '#FFFFF', size: '25px' }}>
      <div className="accordionSection">
        <div className = "container">
          {product.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <>
                <div className = "wrap" onClick={() => toggle(index)} key={index}>
                  <h1>Ingredientes</h1>
                  <span>{clicked === index ? <FiMinus /> : <FiPlus />}</span>
                </div>
                {clicked === index ? (
                  <div className="dropdown">
                    <p>{item.ingredients}</p>
                  </div>
                ) : null}
              </>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </IconContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

ProductScreen.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';
import Accordion from '../components/Accordion';


export default function ProductScreen(props) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const productId = props.match.params.id;
    const productDetails = useSelector((state) => state.productDetails);
    const { loading, error, product } = productDetails;
    const userSignin = useSelector((state) => state.userSignin);
    const { userInfo } = userSignin;
   
  
    return (
        <div>
            {loading ? (
                <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
            ) : error ? (
                <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
            ) : (
                <div>
                    <Link to="/body">Back to result</Link>
                    <div className="row top">            
                        <div className="col-1">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <h1>{product.name}</h1>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                <div>
                                   <Accordion />
                                </div>
                               </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-1">
                            <div className="card card-body">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <div className="row">
                                            <div>Price</div>
                                            <div className="price">${product.price}</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                   
                                    
                                            <li>
                                                <button onClick={addToCartHandler} className="primary block">
                                                    Add to Cart
                                                </button>
                                            </li>
                                        </>
                                    )}
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                                    
                                ) : (
                                    <MessageBox>
                                        Please <Link to="/signin">Sign In</Link> to write a review
                                    </MessageBox>
                                )}
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```